# Minimal Web Api Not Returning Desired Result

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database, minimal-apis

I have created a minimal ASP.NET Core Web API project in Visual Studio. And then deploying this to Azure Web App Service to be able to 'GET' results remotely. Locally, the /weatherforecast sample data runs fine as well as the Azure SQL data, however, after publishing it, only the weatherforecast is accessible but /Members isn't.

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
});
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");

app.MapGet("/Members", () => {
        var rows = new List<string>();

        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER", conn);
        using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        { 
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                rows.Add($"{reader.GetInt32(0)}, {reader.GetString(1)}, {reader.GetString(2)}, {reader.GetString(3)}, {reader.GetString(4)}, {reader.GetInt32(5)}, {reader.GetInt32(6)}, {reader.GetDecimal(7)}, {reader.GetInt32(8)}, {reader.GetDateTime(9)}");
            }
        }

        return rows;
    })
    .WithName("GetMembers")
    .WithOpenApi();


app.Run();

internal record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

[image: Service Dependencies]

General Notes:

1. My account credentials in Visual Studio are the same as in Azure Portal running Azure SQL.
2. I have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/azure-sql-dotnet-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=visual-studio%2Cazure-portal) link for the project.
3. My connection string is "Server=tcp:xxx;Database=xxx;Authentication=Active Directory Default;" which is declared under environmentVariable in launchSettings.json. Also delcared in appsettings.json.
4. I get a HTTP ERROR 500 when /Members endpoint called.

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: _"only the weatherforecast is accessible but /Members isn't."_, _"I get a HTTP ERROR 500 when /Members endpoint called."_ - I would say that it is accessible (but not working).

Comment: _"which is declared under environmentVariable in launchSettings.json"_ - launchSettings are used only for dev environments and are not published. You need to check the logs and see what exact error is happening.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you very much for all your input. Just came back from holidays. Would you mind telling where/how I can check these logs please?

Comment: I have not worked with Azure much but I'm sure it should store logs somewhere where you can see actual error. Also you can try temporary adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` so the actual error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

> which is declared under environmentVariable in launchSettings.json. Also delcared in appsettings.json.

[Docs about launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson):

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - Contains profile settings.

> `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");`

`appsettings.json` do not affect environment variables, they are used to provide configuration values - check out [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) docs.

I would recommend not to get values from the environment variables directly but use them as one of configuration sources following the more idiomatic approach. To access configuration you can use `Configuration` property exposed both by builder and app, for example:

```cs
var value = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");
var value = app.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");
```

Quite often connection strings are placed into `ConnectionStrings` section, for example in appsettings in can look like:

```json
{
  // ...
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING" : "..."
  }
}
```

Then it can be accessed via `GetConnectionString` method:

```cs
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");
```

Also check the [Connection string prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#connection-string-prefixes) section of the docs.

But in general I highly recommend to go over the aforementioned configuration doc and determine the best approach for your use case ([there are several configuration sources options specifically for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-providers)).

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is happening, that it can't get the environmental variable declared in `launchSettings.json` simply because this file is not being published because it is meant to use in dev environment. Since it can't get the value of this env variable, it falls back to `string.Empty` which you're trying to use later to connect. 500 error indicates that something is terribly wrong, in this case, you're trying to connect to DB using "" (empty string) as a connections string.

If you already have it declared in your `appsettings.json` then you should be able to grab connection string like this, instead of the environmental variable

```
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");
```

Assuming that your connection string is defined as follows

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING" : "..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Connection string is defined correctly in appsettings.json as you have kindly pointed out and instead of getting environment variable, I have replaced it with your line using builder.Configuration property. Still not working unfortunately. Error 500.